# Reverse for 'update_order' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update_order\\/(?P<pk>[^/]+)\\/$']

Tags: django, django-templates

I guess there is some error in updateorder function, but I cannot find it. When I am clicking on the update button in **dashboard.html** it gives an error saying that

> Reverse for 'update_order' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update_order\/(?P[^/]+)\/$']

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from accounts.models import *
from accounts.forms import OrderForm

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    customers = Customer.objects.all()
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    total_customers = customers.count()
    total_orders = orders.count()
    pending = orders.filter(status='Pending').count()
    delivered = orders.filter(status='Delivered').count()
    context = {'customers':customers, 'orders':orders, 'pending':pending, 'delivered':delivered, 'total_customers':total_customers,
                    'total_orders':total_orders}
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)

def products(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'accounts/products.html', {'products':products})

def customer(request, pk):
    customers = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    orders_counts = orders.count()
    context = {'customers':customers, 'orders':orders, 'orders_counts':orders_counts}
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer.html', context)


def createorder(request):

    form = OrderForm
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/order_form.html', context)


def updateorder(request, pk):
    orders = Order.objects.get(id = pk)
    form = OrderForm(instance = orders)
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/order_form.html', context)

> Blockquote
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
    path('products/', views.products, name = 'products'),
    path('customer/<str:pk>/', views.customer, name = 'customer'),
    path('create_order/', views.createorder, name = 'create_order'),
    path('update_order/<str:pk>/', views.updateorder, name = 'update_order')

]
```

dashboard.html

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% include 'accounts/status.html' %}

<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h5>CUSTOMERS:</h5>
    <hr>
    <div class="card card-body">
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" href="">CREATE CUSTOMERS</a>
      <table class = "table table-sm">
        <tr>
          <th>Customers</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>

        {% for i in customers %}
          <tr>
            <!-- <td><a href="{% url 'customer' i.id %}">View</a></td> -->
            <td>{{i.name}}</td>
            <td>{{i.phone}}</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="{% url 'customer' i.id %}">View</a></td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-7">
    <h5>LAST 5 ORDERS</h5>
    <hr>
    <div class="card card-body">
      <a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="{% url 'create_order' %}">CREATE ORDERS</a>
      <table class = "table table-sm">
        <tr>
          <th>Product</th>
          <th>Date Ordered</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Update</th>
          <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>

        {% for i in orders %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{i.product}}</td>
            <td>{{i.date_created}}</td>
            <td>{{i.status}}</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="{% url 'update_order' Order.id %}">Update</a></td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="">Delete</a></td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}

      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from accounts.models import Order

class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

order_forms.html

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<form  method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{form}}
  <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is that the entire error message? Can you narrow this down a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for i in orders %}
    ...
    {% url 'update_order' Order.id %}
```

it's `i`, not `Order`, so change to

```
    {% url 'update_order' i.id %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For [django-1.x](/questions/tagged/django-1.x), you can not use such `path(..)`s, and in that case you need to **write a regular expression**, like:

```
    url(r'^complete/(?P<todo_id>[0-9]+)$', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
```

If you are using [django-2.x](/questions/tagged/django-2.x), you probably want to use **`path(..)`**, like you have.

I believe it may be to do with how you've set up your regex. What data type is the `Order` object from your models, I am assuming they're string since that's the type you have defined in your urls. If they're then do as you've done , else if its string then do what's below

For urls, instead of this:

`url('update_order/<todo_id>', , views.updateorder, name = 'update_order'),`

try this:

```
url(r'^update_order/(?P<todo_id>\d+)$', , views.updateorder, name = 'update_order'),
```

Or incase you want to use [`path`]

```
path('update_order/<int:todo_id>', views.updateorder, name = 'update_order'),
```